# i3wm Dunst no longer showing notifications

Tags: notification, ubuntu-minimal, i3-wm

I an running a minimal install of Ubuntu with i3wm. `dunst` was running fine until I installed feh wich is I think is totally unrelated.

When I try to send a test notification using

```
notify-send "test"
```

nothing happend.

I looked to see if any other notification deamon was running
for `dunst`:

```
$ ps aux | grep dunst
spark     1475  0.0  0.6  55100 13096 ?        Sl   22:39   0:00 /usr/bin/dunst
spark     1896  0.0  0.3  42976  7696 pts/0    Sl   22:44   0:00 dunst
spark     4012  0.0  0.1   4548  2060 pts/0    S+   22:56   0:00 grep --color=auto dunst
```

searching `noti` gave

```
$ ps aux | grep noti
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:38   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
spark     4885  0.0  0.0   4552  2008 pts/0    S+   23:09   0:00 grep --color=auto noti
```

and osd

```
$ ps aux | grep osd
spark     5096  0.0  0.1   4548  2124 pts/0    R+   23:12   0:00 grep --color=auto osd
```

When I try to start `dunst` I get:

```
$ dunst
Warning: Unknown keyboard shortcut: ctrl+grave
Name Lost. Is Another notification daemon running?
```

At this point I don't know what to do exactly as no notifications are showing up at all, and they were working fine until I restarted my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind it was working fine.

I changed my config for dunst in `~/.config/dunst/dunstrc` to

```
transparency = 0
```

I'd previously set it to `100` which I thought would make it opaque, but it made it invisible.